# How do use a mod_rewrite to eliminate the "/%year%/ from WordPress URL?

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, date

How do use a mod_rewrite to eliminate the `"/%year%/` from WordPress URL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Login to WordPress as the Administrator. Go to Settings -> Permalinks and customize the link structure from there. Reference the [Permalinks Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) page for more help.

**Additionally if you are unable to change the settings from here than it may be due to the file permissions set on the .htaccess in your WordPress root. Change the permissions so it's writeable, follow the above instructions, and then reset the permissions back to what it was before.